# Converting a laptop with a Spanish keyboard to an English keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboards

I'm buying a laptop with a Spanish keyboard. Can I convert it to an English keyboard manually, by replacing the Spanish keys?

Comment: In theory, assuming they have the same key placements, yes. In practicality this will mean anything from regluing keys if the keyboard is membrane design to straight up breaking scissor switches and then trying to find matching ones online. Unless the keys are designed to be easily removed, this will probably be a pain in the butt.

Comment: There are inexpensive USB foldable keyboards for about US$5. It might be easier to use that, rather than buy a replacement keyboard. You may also need to install the English layout in the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace the physical keyboard and change the keyboard language settings in OS to english. I recommend not removing keys one by one, but changing the whole keyboard instead. This might void your guarantee though.

The procedure is easy, I replaced my first laptop keyboard in my life successfully with the help of random youtube video. So you can do it yourself too.